# Using nested DLookUP with Null values not returning results #Error

Tags: ms-access-2016, dlookup

I have a form that selects the customer name. Once the customer is selected, the subform shows a list of plots they own. I am trying to bring up who is buried in each plot in the subform. I just need the name to show up which in a different table. I think part of the problem is that in my plot table, the same customer can own several plots. Some plots are empty and some plots are full.

I have tried nested DLookUp statements. I have tried a DLookUp with Select statements. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

```
=DLookUp("[Buried_FN] & ' ' & [Buried_MI] & ' ' & [Buried_LN]","[Burial_Info]","[Burial_Info]![BuriedID]=" & DLookUp("[Plot]![BuriedID]","[Plot]","[Plot]![OwnerID1]=" & [Forms]![Owner_Info]![SelectedCust].[Column](0)))
```

So I have 3 tables that I am working with in all right now.
Owner_Info
Plot
Burial_Info

In my Plot table, I have a field for OwnerID1 which is the ID for Owner_Info.
I also have a BuriedID in Plot that is the same BuriedID in Burial_Info.

What I need in my subform is to show the name from the Burial_Info table if the plot has a burial and show nothing when it is still open.

[Picture of Form I'm Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmfMb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with that seems to work.

```
=IIf(IsNull([BuriedID]),"",DLookUp("[Buried_FN] & ' ' & [Buried_MI] & ' ' & [Buried_LN]","[qry_BuriedName]","[qry_BuriedName]![ID]=" & [Forms]![Owner_Info]![SelectedCust].[Column](0) & " AND [qry_BuriedName]![BuriedID]=" & [BuriedID]))
```

In case anybody else needs help with it.